# Scheduled Reports

Tags: wordpress

I am getting the following issue when trying to scheduling a report. I am using wordpress

Entity: Job Action: mail_report
Summary
Finished execution of Recent Adoption V1 with result: Failure, Error message: A fatal error was triggered: You do not have permission to access this page.
Details

Parameters raw (from db settings): 
instanceId=1
format=csv

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:3:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:1:"1";s:6:"format";s:3:"csv";}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Recent Adoption V1 with result: Failure, Error message: A fatal error was triggered: You do not have permission to access this page.

Comment: Check your permissions under Administer - Users and Permissions - Permissions and there's a link there to Wordpress Access Control, i.e. `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1`.